# Laravel não consegue encontrar minha classe

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um controller que é localizado em:

`app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController` que possui a função login.

Criei uma rota no meu api.php pra quando bater em login acessar meu método:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Meu login controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller

...
```

Eu recebo:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found"

Se eu trocar a rota e deixar apenas:

```
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Eu recebo:

> "Class App\Http\Controllers\LoginController does not exist"

Gostaria de saber como corrigir isso e porque o laravel é tão ruim com a localização dos arquivos?

Comment: As pastas estão estrururadas corretamente? O `composer.json` está configurado corretamente?

Comment: Eu tenho uma classe RegisterController no mesmo diretório que essa classe LoginController. O laravel encontra o registercontroller mas não encontra o logincontroller

Comment: Utilize o comando `composer dump-autoload` ou utilize o parâmetro `namespace`, por exemplo: `Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function () {
    // Load Controllers "App\Http\Controllers\Auth"
});`

Answer (score -4):

Você deve especificar todo o caminho até a classe controller, neste caso a LoginController. Então, você usar uma destas duas opções:

1ª) Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login');

ou

2ª)

use App/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController;

Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Este site é o [pt.so], portanto todo conteúdo deve estar em português